# Can I use simple past along with present perfect like this?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect

The sentence is, for example,

- The researchers **investigated** and **found** that due to the rise
  of AI bots, most of the existing works **have focused** on protecting
  the email services from spam.

Is this structure considered wrong speaking of tense use?

Comment: No, it's fine. However, I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi cpx, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: @Chappo: Thanks, I will delete it. But I just want to be clear that since researchers found the information in past, by using present perfect I am saying it is still relevant in present? Can you elaborate your comment on this?

Comment: If what the researchers found is still correct (rather than some historic fact that has since become untrue), then present perfect correctly indicates that the *past* fact is *presently* true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The researchers investigated and found that . . .

This part of the sentence happened in the past. The concluding part of the sentence can talk about the past, present or future, relative to that point in time, and still be fine, so long as it is still true:

> a) . . . robots **had plotted** to take over the world.
>   b) . . . robots **are plotting** to take over the world.
>   c) . . . robots **will plot** to take over the world.

So long as the statement has not been proven to be false in some way since the investigation occurred, the particular time frame is still valid.

For instance, if, many months later, robots are *still* plotting to take over the word, then b) remains an accurate statement.

---

This is in line with reported speech where, if the thing reported is still true, you do not *need* to backshift the tense—it can optionally remain in the present (or future):

> Mary **told** me that she **is** sorry. (And she still is.)
>   Mary **told** me that she **will** be sorry in 2030. (A date still to come, when, as much as the future can be predicted, something will happen.)

If, however, the thing is no longer a true statement, then the tense should remain in the past—rather than refer to a present or future event or situation:

> Mary **told** me that she **was** fine. (She has since died.)

---

**Note**: To be clear, there are many possible specific verb conjugations that can be used. The actual sentence from the question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you also include ". . . robots have plotted" in the answer?

Comment: @cpx Yes, indeed. There are many variations of verb conjugations that could be used. I just picked a single one for past, present, and future.